# HyLang import_buffer_to_ast removed version 0.18.0

Tags: hy

I am updating from Hy 0.12.1 to the newest version 0.18.0, and I make heavy use of the import_buffer_to_ast function in my python code.

This function has been removed from hy.importer, I was hoping someone could lead me to a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

`hy.importer` comprises mostly internal Hy functions, which are liable to change without notice. You can try using new internal functions like `ast_compile` or `hy_compile`, but hopefully you can get what you need out of public functions like `hy.eval`, `hy.read_str`, and `hy.read`.